# Advanced Installer self -signedtool but no changes?

Tags: java, windows-installer, exe, sign, advanced-installer

I'm actually building several installers for my Java apps and also .Net apps using *Advanced Installer*. Everything works smoothly right until the popup appeared once the installer -run, "Unknown-publisher".

So I google around, and I found out that I need to use the signtool given. And luckily Advanced Installer has that features, but... why is the output-installer.exe still producing 'unknown publisher' as it was earlier? Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a self-signed certificate (generated by you) or a certificate purchased from a certified vendor? (Thawtee, Comodo, Verisign, etc...)

To have your digital signature recognized on any Windows device you need to buy a certificate from one of the certified vendors. Self-signed (self-generated) certificates will not help you in this case. (Self signed certificates are useful in other scenarios, but to keep this simple I will not go into details now)

If you have the budget, I recommend an EV certificate, it will save you some trouble with Microsoft's SmartScreen system.

Here is a [list of code signing certificate vendors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/code-signing-cert-manage) Microsoft seems to recommend.